# bluetooth stopped working on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: bluetooth

after a while, bluetooth stopped working on ubuntu 16.04, while it still works fine on windows. The indicator is on, but when I go on Bluetotoh services, and start devices search, it just keeps searching without findind anything.
I tried many suggestions found online with no results.

these are a few debug outputs:

```
sudo service bluetooth status

● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since mar 2018-02-27 00:09:03 CET; 10min ago
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
 Main PID: 943 (bluetoothd)
   Status: "Running"
   CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
           └─943 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

feb 27 00:09:03 marco-X550JF bluetoothd[943]: Not enough free handles to register service
feb 27 00:09:03 marco-X550JF bluetoothd[943]: Sap driver initialization failed.
feb 27 00:09:03 marco-X550JF bluetoothd[943]: sap-server: Operation not permitted (1)
feb 27 00:09:11 marco-X550JF bluetoothd[943]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.36 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
feb 27 00:09:11 marco-X550JF bluetoothd[943]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.36 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
feb 27 00:09:17 marco-X550JF bluetoothd[943]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.69 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
feb 27 00:09:17 marco-X550JF bluetoothd[943]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.69 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
feb 27 00:09:17 marco-X550JF bluetoothd[943]: RFCOMM server failed for Headset Voice gateway: rfcomm_bind: Address already in use (98)
feb 27 00:09:32 marco-X550JF bluetoothd[943]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.36 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
feb 27 00:09:32 marco-X550JF bluetoothd[943]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.36 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
```

and

```
dmesg | grep Blue
[    1.485255] usb 3-5: Product: Bluetooth Radio 
[   20.381051] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[   20.381079] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   20.381081] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   20.381083] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   20.381087] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   20.390200] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: examining hci_ver=06 hci_rev=000a lmp_ver=06 lmp_subver=8821
[   20.390202] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: loading rtl_bt/rtl8821a_config.bin
[   20.525847] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: loading rtl_bt/rtl8821a_fw.bin
[   20.575191] Bluetooth: hci0: rom_version status=0 version=1
[   20.575195] Bluetooth: cfg_sz 0, total size 17428
[   24.759641] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   24.759642] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   24.759644] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   32.342069] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   32.342073] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   32.342076] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[   34.368047] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x0c24 tx timeout
[   36.380036] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x0c52 tx timeout
```

rfkill list:

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

any ideas? thanks